# Google CSE - jump to specific keyword

Tags: html, google-custom-search

i'm currently working with the google cse and i wonder wether it's possible to jump to a specific searchword. for example if i goole on my page the word publications, and there is a section of publications on a page, is it possible to jump directly to this section by using the implemented google search?

at the moment every search i do, leads me to the beginning of the page where the keyword is placed.

greetings martin

Answer (score 0):

This is possible, yes, but you would have to do some coding.  If you think about how the Google search works, it just generates a list of links.  It has no control over what happens once you reach the other page.  So, anything that you wanted to happen on the destination page, you would have to code yourself.  If you really want to do this, you could set it up something like this:

First, you will want to use a V1 CSE, since it offers the ability to set a callback function on search complete, which the new, simplified V2 does not.  See V1 documentation here: https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/js/cselement-devguide

Here's the sample code from that page, modified to add a callback function:

```
<!--
  copyright (c) 2012 Google inc.

  You are free to copy and use this sample.
-->

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <title>Google Custom Search Element API Example</title>
    <script src="https://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        google.load('search', '1');
        google.setOnLoadCallback(function(){
          customSearchControl = new google.search.CustomSearchControl().draw('cse');
        }, true);
          customSearchControl.setSearchCompleteCallback(this, searchCompleteFn);
    </script>
  </head>
  <body style="font-family: Arial;border: 0 none;">
    <div id="cse" style="width:100%;">Loading...</div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Then you can create that callback function like so:

```
function searchCompleteFn(control, searcher) {
    //your code
}
```

In your code, you would want to get all the a.gs-title elements within the cse div and modify their href attributes to add the user's query.  That way your destination page can see what the user searched for and take appropriate action (scroll to the appropriate section, highlight the keywords, whatever you want).  For example, if the existing href is http://www.yoursite.com/somepath/somepage.html, you could change it to http://www.yoursite.com/somepath/somepage.html#query=[user_query].

[user_query] is given by control.getInputQuery()

Finally, on your destination pages you would have javascript check for a query parameter in location.hash, and act appropriately.

I'm guessing this is way more work than you're interested in doing, but perhaps it will be helpful to someone.